# pdb's PATH is different?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

I have a script that sources a local copy of a python library using the following code:

```
# get our local copy of pybst
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0] + "/../libs/")

from pybst import avltree
```

When I run with `python script.py` everything runs fine. However, when I run `pdb script.py` and start to step through, I get an `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: 'No module named pybst
```

If I change the sys path line to use `../libs` instead (no first slash), `pdb` works fine but `python` breaks.

Why does this happen? Does `pdb` modify the `sys.path` variable in a different way than `python` does?

---

EDIT:
So here's something interesting, I inserted a `print sys.path` right before the insert, and here's what I found (with `pdb`):

```
before:
    sys.path[0] = '/../libs/'
after
    sys.path[0] = '/../libs//../libs/'
```

and while running with Python:

```
before: sys.path[0] = /path/to/my/script
```

Comment: Python does not load modules from `PATH`, but it does use `PYTHONPATH` if it is set.  Have you modified `PYTHONPATH`?  As a workaround, try running it as `python -m pdb script.py`

Comment: A better solution may be to use `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..', 'libs'))`. Make sure to `import os`. Does that work?

Comment: Why don't you just `import pdb` at the beginning of your script then manually add `pdb.set_trace()` at whatever lines you want, then start the script as usual?

Comment: @RushyPanchal your solution worked great, thanks, but do you have any insight into why this occurred in the first place? This question is mainly out of curiosity more than anything else

Comment: @Jeeter I'd imagine that `sys.path[0]` is not the same for both `pdb` and `python`. Although `sys.path[0]` is *usually* the working directory, it's safer to just get the current working directory (through `os.getcwd()`) and then add on your desired path. For path manipulations, `os.path` is also safer because it'll generate valid paths regardless of system.

Comment: @RushyPanchal you and I are on the same mindset :). I printed `sys.path` before and after the insert, and look what happens!